React Native App Build Failure: Assistance Needed
I created a React Native app, but when I run the command npm start for Android, the build fails repeatedly. I need assistance to resolve this issue so I can run the app smoothly and continue development. Any help is appreciated.

the build fails is not enough information to help you. Surely you have more information about WHY it is failing in an error message only you can see. I'm going to go out on a limb and speculate that you haven't got the build tools for Android installed at all

please provide us with more information or a piece of code or error logs to help you out

The bundler is voice-activated
